# Batch delete items for a dynamodb table with hash and range key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to perform a batch write item for a dynamodb table using boto3 python library. The table has both hash and range key. When I performed the same with another table with only hash key it worked well. I am wondering how to add both hash and range key when performing batch write item operation.

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr,Key

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('edc_test')

scan = table.scan(
    #ProjectionExpression='#k',
    ProjectionExpression='resource_id',
    #ProjectionExpression='version_id',
    FilterExpression=Attr('Health.New version - Veracity unavailable').eq("A new dataset is available but IDQ rules are not generated yet")
)
items=scan['Items']
print('length',str(len(items)))
print(items)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for each in scan['Items']:
            batch.delete_item(Key=each)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ProjectionExpression='version_id,resource_id',
    FilterExpression=Attr('Health.New version - Veracity unavailable').eq("A new dataset is available but IDQ rules are not generated yet")
#ExpressionAttributeNames={
#    '#k': 'name'
#}
    )
items=scan['Items']
print('length',str(len(items)))
print(items)


#response = table.table.delete_item(Key={resource_id:1})

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    #for each in scan['Items']:
     #   batch.delete_item(Key=each)
    for each in scan['Items']:
            #batch.delete_item(Key={'version_id': each['version_id']})
            batch.delete_item(Key={'resource_id': each['resource_id'], 'version_id': each['version_id']})
```

Included sort key in scan projection expression and included the same in delete batch item , it worked.